# Open file in $EDITOR by default in zsh

Tags: zsh

In zsh, if you can open directories without specifying cd command, like this

```
% pwd
/home/user/test
% ls
integration shared unit
% unit
% pwd
/home/user/test/unit
```

This effectively saves writing 'cd' everytime you try to open a directory. However it's smart enough not to 'cd' into files. Would it be possible to open a file without specifying $EDITOR command?

For example,

```
% ls
test
% test
% pwd
/users/home/test
% ls 
test.rb
% test.rb
... opens in an editor ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zsh does support this through **suffix aliases**. Try this:

```
% alias -s rb=$EDITOR
% touch foo.rb
% foo.rb  # it opens
```

I have a long list of suffix aliases in `~/.zshrc`. This ruby extension is not a great example since program files often want to be executed, and now it surprisingly opens. It also may cause confusion with scripts in your `path` with conflicting names (which `foo.rb`?). It makes more sense for things like pdf, flac, mp4, csv, etc, when you don't want to remember which is your favorite app for the file type:

```
% alias -s pdf=evince
```